# Making the column variable in a Nested loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with trying to expand on the code that I have written.  The code I have pasted below is currently working as intended.  The issue I have is that I am trying to make the "P2" cell variable.  Essentially, I am trying to compare the ("K" & i) cell in the loop to all the dates in the range P2 to AA2 on my sheet.  Then if the month and year matches, paste the data in the corresponding column that matched.  I have tried replacing the column reference P with another integer, but could not get the nested loop to function correctly.  Is there a different way to establish a column as a variable?  Thank you for your help.

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

For i = 3 To 6

    If Month(Range("K" & i)) = Month(Range("P2")) And Year(Range("K" & i)) = Year(Range("P2")) And Range("J" & i).Value > "0" Then

       Range("J" & i).Copy
       Range("P" & i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Is the "End If" still supposed to be uncommented?

Comment: Use `Application.WorskSheetFunction.Match()` to find the correct column.  And use it's return to set the column.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the columns 16 through 27 inside your existing loop:

```
Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

For i = 3 To 6
    'loop columns p through aa
    For k = 16 to 27

        'Instead of Range() we are using Cell() to refer to the column variabl-y... Cells(<rownum>,<columnnum>)
        If Month(Range("K" & i)) = Month(Cells(2,k)) And Year(Range("K" & i)) = Year(Cells(2,k)) And Range("J" & i).Value > "0" Then

           Range("J" & i).Copy
           Cells(i,k).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        End If
    Next k

Next i


End Sub
```